# Best Datasets and Packages for Comparing LASSO, Elastic Net, and Ridge

Tags: r, dataset, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

I have been recently been working with the `MASS`, `lars`, and `glmnet` packages to study variable selection and prediction via LASSO, Ridge Regression, and the Elastic Net. To compare these methods against one another, I have been using some Boston Housing Market data (`BH0`) but I am not entirely sure that this dataset captures a good comparison amongst the methods since there are 505 observations and only 17 predictors for each response.

In general, I know that the LASSO method follows $L_1$-norm regularization while Ridge Regression follows $L_2$-norm regularization, and Elastic Net is a combination of the two methods to *hopefully* maximize on the advantages of each method. Further, I know that Ridge Regression is often the preferred method when the number of predictors $p$ is large compared to the number of observations $n$, or when there are concerns of multicollinearity among the predictors.

**My question:**

Are there any particular packages or datasets that would be good for comparing LASSO, Ridge Regression, and Elastic Net methods against one another, or any recommendations for datasets?

Comment: *I know that Ridge Regression is often the preferred method when the number of predictors $p$  is large compared to the number of observations $n$* – in such settings ridge may be preferred to OLS or other unpenalized methods but generally not to LASSO or elastic net. Each of ridge, LASSO and elastic net address the issue in a similar way and either one can be more or less effective than their competitors depending on other characteristics of the problem.

Comment: You could try some of the datasets that other researchers have used for similar comparisons. A fairly recent one is Hastie et al. ["Best Subset, Forward Stepwise or Lasso? Analysis and Recommendations Based on Extensive Comparisons"](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/bestsubset-sts.pdf), perhaps you will find some relevant datasets referenced there. If not there, then in some other comparison papers or papers where the methods were introduced (Tibshirani's lasso paper, Zou & Hastie's elastic net paper and similar).